# How can I safely tie the output of a sensor high or low?

Tags: sensor, esp8266, pir

I would like to ask a general question and get a discursive answer, but I know that's discouraged here so I'll ask the general question, then pose a more specific one.

**In general:** What happens if I tie the output of a binary, logic level sensor high or low, will it damage the output of the sensor? I am guessing the answer depends on what the sensor is, in which case are there common features to look for when trying to understand how that sensor works, such as a resistor on the output stage? The binary logic-level sensors I'm talking about would be breakout boards like small PIRs such as the AM312 or microwave sensor breakout boards.

**Specifically:** Assuming you have no idea what I mean by the above, let me pose this question more specifically. I have a 5V microwave sensor breakout board, an RCWL-0516. I have a microcontroller (ESP8265) with only one digital input, but I wish to connect this microwave sensor AND a physical retractive switch to this input pin, i.e. in parallel. This is so that either the retractive switch OR the sensor could cause a trigger. Should I simply place a resistor inline between the sensor output and the microcontroller input?

Comment: Maybe consider an OR gate?

Comment: Try to find RCWL-0516 schematics. Which chip does it use, and is there anything else than a series resistor to output pin? Most of these claim push-pull output, so perhaps simply put a 10k in series with ESP input pin to the module, and simply connect pushbutton between ESP input and VCC.

Comment: Thanks @Justme, I found a documentation project on GitHub, apparently the IC on the low frequency side is called the RCWL-9196 and is "very similar to the BISS0001". It has a resistor called R1 which is marked as "100", presumably 100Ohm.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the output of one sensor goes high and stays there - it is acceptable that you no longer get triggers from the other sensor?

Comment: use the output of the RCWL-0516 to drive a transistor to create an open collector output ... the switch can be connected in parallel with the transistor ... activating the sensor or pressing the switch will pull the output low

Comment: @brhans Yes that is acceptable. In the specific example, one sensor will be a movement sensor and the other a retractive switch to be pressed by a human.